# MS Access Focus not shifting to subform

Tags: database, forms, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a main form with a subform and a second, nested, subform. I'm having an issue where if I open a blank form and input data into the main form and then try to move to a text box on one of the subforms I am unable to use the textbox. However, If I open the form and immediately navigate to one of the subforms, I am able to go back to the main form. I've noted that the subform's Enter event does not fire if I have attempted data entry in the main form. Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, turns out I forgot to remove a BeforeUpdate event on my main form that was meant to block the record from being saved until a certain button was clicked.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not save Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
    End Sub
```

Where `save` is boolean variable set to true if the save button is pressed.